# Fixing multiple buildpath errors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I am working on a MineCraft project at home and at school using eclipse.  I can export my project at home and import it at school, however after I import there are 60 build path errors.

At home all of the .jar files are in:
\users\clark\ .gradle\caches...*.jar
At school all of the .jar files are in almost the same place
\users\cs\ .gradle\caches...*.jar

Question 4488247 on StackOverflow shows me how to fix a build path error.  However, I would like to avoid making 60 buildpath changes each time I import.

Is there a different way to export to indicate that the build path is relative to my location?  Or is there a file that I can update the build path in and do a simple search and replace?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like both those directories are your home directory? If so, you should be able to use `~/.gradle/caches...*.jar` for both environments. The other thing you could do if that doesn't work is have two `.classpath` files `home.classpath` and `school.classpath` and rename the appropriate one to `.classpath` and refresh your project in Eclipse. The `.classpath` file is the file that holds all the classpath entries.

I would highly recommend using the [Gradle plugin for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-sts-integration-eclipse). I haven't used it, but it should help you manage these classpath entries automatically.

Comment: Thanks Samuel!  The .classpath file was what I needed.  I edited that and changed the directory names and all 60 errors were gone.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If my answer was correct, please click the checkmark next to the answer to indicate your question has been solved :)